# Loading views after the UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification, uiapplicationdelegate

I would like to display view on the touch of the alert of the local notification, my problem is given below

Their are three views v1, v2,v3 and i have triggered code on the button of these three different views the code for that is given below and varies from different views

```
notificationObject_ViewOne = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
notificationObject_ViewOne.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:20];
notificationObject_ViewOne.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notificationObject_ViewOne.alertBody = @"You are notified";
notificationObject_ViewOne.alertAction = @"View 1";
notificationObject_ViewOne.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;

NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Object 1", @"Key 1", nil];
notificationObject_ViewOne.userInfo = infoDict;


[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notificationObject_ViewOne];
[notificationObject_ViewOne release];

SecondViewController *sec = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];

[sec release];
```

The code to trigger notification in the second view is

```
notificationObject_ViewTwo = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
notificationObject_ViewTwo.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:35];
notificationObject_ViewTwo.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notificationObject_ViewTwo.alertBody = @"You are notified";
notificationObject_ViewTwo.alertAction = @"View 2";
notificationObject_ViewTwo.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;

NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Object 2", @"Key 2", nil];
notificationObject_ViewTwo.userInfo = infoDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notificationObject_ViewTwo];

[notificationObject_ViewTwo release];

ThirdViewController *ThirdObj = [[ThirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:ThirdObj animated:YES];

[ThirdObj release];
```

Now inside the app delegate i am handling the notification with the code given below

```
UILocalNotification *localNotificationObject = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

if (localNotificationObject) 
{

    firstObject = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSLog(@"noti %@",[localNotificationObject.userInfo valueForKey:@"Key 1"]);

    // firstObject.title = @"FirstView";
    [self.window addSubview:firstObject.view];

}

else if(localNotificationObject)
{
    SecondViewController *secondObject = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSLog(@"noti %@",[localNotificationObject.userInfo valueForKey:@"Key 2"]);

    [self.window addSubview:secondObject.view];

    //secondObject.title = @"Second View";
}

else if(localNotificationObject)
{
    ThirdViewController *thirdObject = [[ThirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSLog(@"noti %@",[localNotificationObject.userInfo valueForKey:@"Key 3"]);

    [self.window addSubview:thirdObject.view];

    // thirdObject.title = @"Third View";
}
else
{
    firstObject = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstObject];


    [self.window addSubview:navC.view]; 
}
```

The above code is written in application did finish launch method of the app delegate file

So what i want to do here is when alert box for notification 1 comes v1 should load, when alert for notification 2 comes v2 should load.

but the thing is v1 is getting loaded perfectly but when it comes to v2 and v3 the userInfo for them is null and v1 is loaded by default. I did the same in the UIApplication delegate method for handling local notification but still the same results.

Kindly provide me some guidance or links for the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never check your key's value you just check to see if it's there.  Look at your first if statement. It's a good thing you used elses or you would have loaded all of them.